# Why do some data don't save on my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm having a problem on saving the data on my database. I mean, for instance in my announcement_request table, the title, description, image path are saving on the database, except the `submittedBy` and `batchYr`.

my request_announcement.php is this:

```
<?php

$login_session =$row['username'];
$position = $row['position'];
$login_fname = $row['firstname'];
$login_lname = $row['lastname'];
$batchYr = $row['batchYr'];

$submittedBy = $login_fname.' '.$login_lname;
if(isset($login_session) and $position=='President'){
?>

            <form action="../pres/send_request_announcement.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <label>Submitted by:</label>
                <input type="text" name="submittedBy" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $submittedBy;?>" disabled > <br/>

                <label>Batch Year:</label>
                <input type="text" name="batchYr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $batchYr;?>" disabled><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Announcement" style="float: right"/>

                </form>
<?php
}

?>
```

And this is my send_request_announcement.php:

```
<?php 
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $submittedBy = $_POST['submittedBy'];
        $batchYr = $_POST['batchYr'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO announcement_requests (submittedBy, batchYr) VALUES('$submittedBy','$batchYr')";
            mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Announcement Request Sent!'); window.location.assign('../user/home.php');</script>";

    }

?>
```

Comment: you are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: Please, reduce your code keeping only parts that still contain this problem. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if that's the reason then other columns like title, description should not be saved too, but they are saving on the database, just not the `submittedBy` and `batchYr` @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

First off, quit using `mysql_*` its a deprecated and bad extension which you do not want to get used to using.

When it comes to why it wont be saved into the database:
You are using both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions, they are not the same lib, so when you connect to a database with `mysqli` you will not be able to use it with `mysql_*` calls.
Swap all of your `mysql_*` calls to apropriate `mysqli_*` calls and it should work better.

Further... Check out the chapter about `prepared statements` in the php documentation for `mysqli`. It will help you with prevention of  sql-injections, which you are vulnerable for at the moment.

Comment: `mysqli_*` is not deprecated AFAIK. But PDO is better anyway.

Comment: sorry, that was a misstype. Should of course be `mysql_*`. Thanx for pointing that out! :)

Comment: even better than mysqli_i is to use PDO. A great tutorial that helped me with PDO is [(the only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Comment: I concur, `PDO` is better in many ways, i prefer that too, but in this case it might be worth jumping over to `mysqli` as a start, then move over to a more OOP way (either with mysqli or pdo).

Comment: i know mysqli and PDO are better now, but i just want to solve this problem. i don't think it's because of using both mysql_* and mysqli tho, because some data are saving except the `submittedby` and `batchyr`.@Jite

Comment: Yes, reading your updated question I can see that it might not be the issue... Could change: `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` (in request_announcement.php) and see what happens?

Comment: still the same happens. everything is saving except the `submittedBy` and `batchYr` @Jite

Comment: Do they have any values set? Does it enter the if-clause?

Comment: I was able to make it work now. thanks for trying to help me :)@Jite

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what's wrong. The reason why it's not saving on the database even though I have the correct queries, was because in my HTML format which are:

```
<input type="text" name="submittedBy" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $submittedBy;?>" disabled > <br/>
<input type="text" name="batchYr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $batchYr;?>" disabled > <br/>
```

has the `disabled` which is wrong, because disabled textboxes are not included when you send forms, so I used readOnly instead:

```
<input type="text" name="submittedBy" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $submittedBy;?>" readOnly="readOnly">
<input type="text" name="batchYr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $batchYr;?>" readOnly="readOnly">
```

`readOnly` is also not editable. So when you want to save a data on the database without the user editing or input something, just use `readOnly` and not `disabled`.